# how to import kivy using IDE

Tags: kivy

What is the best way to install kivy in pycharm. I am faced with number of errors in trying to install this library. Not sure if this is common .Can someone advise?

Comment: Can you please post what you have attempted and the errors you are seeing so as to allow the community help you..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take note of the articles in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). You may also want to consult [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [the good question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/5698098).

Answer (score 1):

Follow the installation instructions on kivy.org, within the pycharm python environment.

If you have a specific issue with this, ask about the issue, not about the general concept.